# Show if any conditions are present

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been going back to some javascript docs to try and figure this out. But, no luck. What I am trying to do is, basically if any of the data is present show this jsx block.

```
{speaker.email || speaker.room &&
  <>
    <h3>Contact</h3>
    <ul className="list-unstyled">
      <li><a href={"mailto:speaker.email"}>{speaker.email}</a></li>
      <li><span>{speaker.room} {speaker.building}</span></li>
      <li><a href={speaker.phone}><span className="font-weight-bold">{speaker.phone}</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </>
}
```

Is there a way using js or react to have multiple conditions using 'or'?

This is probably a terrible example but something like this:

```
{speaker.email || speaker.room || speaker.building || speaker.phone &&
```

Comment: Does adding parens help? `(speaker.email || speaker.room)`

Comment: I think you need to wrap your  JSX with brackets ( ... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jmargolisvt was right, you can simply wrap with parens.

```
{(speaker.email || speaker.room || speaker.building || speaker.phone) &&
  <>
    ...
  </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, Use if condition and return the JSX

```
if (speaker.email || speaker.room || speaker.building || speaker.phone) { // any number of condition can be joined by || 
    return (
        <>
            <h3>Contact</h3>
            <ul className="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href={"mailto:speaker.email"}>{speaker.email}</a></li>
            <li><span>{speaker.room} {speaker.building}</span></li>
            <li><a href={speaker.phone}><span className="font-weight-bold">{speaker.phone}</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </>
    );   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tested it and it worked like following. temp link https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dhawan-k3yms

```
{speaker.email ||
  (speaker.room && (
    <>
      <h3>Contact</h3>
      <ul className="list-unstyled">
        <li>
          <a href={"mailto:speaker.email"}>{speaker.email}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>
            {speaker.room} {speaker.building}
          </span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href={speaker.phone}>
            <span className="font-weight-bold">{speaker.phone}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </>
  ))}
```